# AWS Lambda usage of ECR: Invalid source image

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecr

**Issue**

I try to use an ECR image via AWS lambda.
AWS keeps saying that my image is invalid, without any further information.

**Steps taken**

I created a docker image based on the default AWS python image:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.10

COPY catalog_sidecar.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

CMD [ "catalog_sidecar.lambda_handler" ]
```

The python file is in the image and the callback handler is correct. I checked that.

I ensured the image is pushed to ECR.

I ensured the correct cross account access policy on the central ECR we use. Regions are correct. account IDs - replaced with **** in code snipped - are correct.

```
{
  "Sid": "permit-test",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::*****:root"
  },
  "Action": "ecr:*"
},
{
  "Sid": "permit-test-lambdas",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
  },
  "Action": "ecr:*",
  "Condition": {
    "StringLike": {
      "aws:sourceArn": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:*****:function:*"
    }
  }
}
```

I moved even to full ECR access to rule issues out with the policy granularity.

**Result**

When I try to use the image out of the UI our out of terraform, the result is always the same

```
Source image ***.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/service-catalog-sidecar@sha256:*** is not valid. Provide a valid source image.
```

I tried both with sha256 hash as well as with tag name version of the URI.

**Question**

I checked multiple instructions and tutorials and they all seem to be aligned with what I did. I am looking for advice how to proceed with that issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your issue with with regions. Your lambda is in eu-west-1 but your image is in eu-central-1 - I have not tested with cross account but within the same account your image must be in same region.

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue. I am used to ECS where cross region access is supported. Unfortunately, the lambda documentation regarding ECR usage is nowhere explicitly stating the region requirement.

Comment: I solved the issue by enabling the cross region replication for our ECR images.

Comment: Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/registry-settings-configure.html